# The element transactionRequest has invalid child element lineItems

Tags: javascript, json, authorize.net, accept.js

I'm trying to send a payment request to Authorize.Net using Accept.js,
They require the "lineItems" to look like this:

```
"lineItems": {
    {
        "lineItem": {
            "itemId": "item1",
            "name": "item1",
            "description": "item1",
            "quantity": "1",
            "unitPrice": "10"
        }
    },
    {
        "lineItem": {
            "itemId": "item2",
            "name": "item2",
            "description": "item2",
            "quantity": "1",
            "unitPrice": "10"
        }
    }
},
```

The problem is that I have each lineitem set as an array, 
And building the json from an array results a json with a squared brackets:

```
"lineItems": [
    {
        "lineItem": {
            "itemId": "item1",
            "name": "item1",
            "description": "item1",
            "quantity": "1",
            "unitPrice": "10"
        }
    },
    {
        "lineItem": {
            "itemId": "item2",
            "name": "item2",
            "description": "item2",
            "quantity": "1",
            "unitPrice": "10"
        }
    }
],
```

Which get the following error:

> The element transactionRequest has invalid child element lineItems,

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
"lineItems": [
    {
        "lineItem": {
            "itemId": "item1",
            "name": "item1",
            "description": "item1",
            "quantity": "1",
            "unitPrice": "10"
        }
    },
    {
        "lineItem": {
            "itemId": "item2",
            "name": "item2",
            "description": "item2",
            "quantity": "1",
            "unitPrice": "10"
        }
    }
],
```

to:

```
"lineItems":
 {
    "lineItem": [
        {
            "itemId": "item1",
            "name": "item1",
            "description": "item1",
            "quantity": "1",
            "unitPrice": "10"
        },
        {
            "itemId": "item2",
            "name": "item2",
            "description": "item2",
            "quantity": "1",
            "unitPrice": "10"
        }
    ]
},
```

Comment: It didn't went through, it seems that they require the "lineItem" word before every lineitem set, you were right changing the "lineItems" to curly brackets, now my question is how do I do that, I'll edit my question with more details.